# Is it possible to set a dynamic window frame bound in SQL OVER(ROW BETWEEN ...)-Clause?

Tags: sql

Consider the following table, describing a patients medication plan. For example, the first row describes that the patient with patient_id = 1 is treated from timestamp 0 to 4. At time = 0, the patient has not yet become any medication (kum_amount_start = 0). At time = 4, the patient has received a kumulated amount of 100 units of a certain drug. It can be assumed, that the drug is given in with a constant rate. Regarding the first row, this means that the drug is given with a rate of 25 units/h.

| patient_id | starttime [h] | endtime [h] | kum_amount_start | kum_amount_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 100 | 300 |
| 1 | 5 | 15 | 300 | 550 |
| 1 | 15 | 18 | 550 | 700 |
| 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 150 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | 150 | 350 |
| 2 | 6 | 10 | 350 | 700 |
| 2 | 10 | 15 | 700 | 1100 |
| 2 | 15 | 19 | 1100 | 1500 |

I want to add the two columns "kum_amount_start_last_6hr" and "kum_amount_end_last_6hr" that describe the amount that has been given within the last 6 hours of the treatment (for the respective timestamps start, end).

I'm stuck with this problem for a while now.

I tried to tackle it with something like this

```
SUM(kum_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id ROWS BETWEEN "dynmaic window size" AND CURRENT ROW)
```

but I'm not sure whether this is the right approach.

I would be very happy if you could help me out here, thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using, but the answer is sometimes "no".

Comment: What do you mean with "Tag your question with the database you are using"? I'm relatively new, sorry.

Comment: It means that to answer your question we need to know which database you are using, if you edit your message you can add a tag for the database (ORACLE, SQL SERVER...) some syntaxes are database specific